# PHP and function

Tags: php, text, explode

Okay so I have the following code:

```
    if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 1 && $data['MAINT'] == True) {
    die ('MM');
}
```

That should technically work but for some reason it doesn't.

Basically in my text file I have said that maint is false but when it gets to this part of the code it still dies.

I think it's something to do with the '$data['MAINT'] == True' part but I am not sure what's wrong with it?

Here is all of the code:

```
$exec = mssql_query("SELECT nEMID, nAuthID, sUserPass FROM tAccounts where sUsername = '$user'");
$AccountData = mssql_fetch_assoc($exec);
$file = file('LauncherInfo.txt');

foreach ($file as $line) {
    if ($line) {
        $splitLine = explode(' = ',$line);
        $data[$splitLine[0]] = $splitLine[1];
    }
}

//echo $data['MAINT'];

if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 2 && $data['MAINT'] == True) {
    //Continue.
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -2) {
    die ('INV');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -1) {
    die ('BAN');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 1 && $data['MAINT'] == True) {
    die ('MM');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 0) {
    die ('EVR');
}
```

This is what is inside the text file 'LauncherInfo.txt':

```
IP = 127.0.0.1
EXE = Client.exe
PORT = 8080
TITLE = Title
MAINT = False
Maintenance-Message = The server is currently in maintenance.
Ban-Message = You have been banned sucker!
Email Verification-Message = You need to active your email adddress.
Investigation-Message = Your account is undergoing investigation.
```

EDIT:

I tried using the following codes:

```
if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -2) {
    die ('INV');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -1) {
    die ('BAN');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 0) {
    die ('EVR');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 1 && $data['MAINT'] == 'True') {
    die ('MM');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 2 && $data['MAINT'] == 'True') {
    //Continue and allow user to log in.
}
```

I also tried this:

```
   if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -2) {
        die ('INV');
    } else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -1) {
        die ('BAN');
    } else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 0) {
        die ('EVR');
    } else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 1 && $data['MAINT'] == "True") {
        die ('MM');
    } else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 2 && $data['MAINT'] == "True") {
        //Continue and allow user to log in.
    }
```

But neither of those work?

EDIT2: I changed my code to look like this:

```
    if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -2) {
    echo ('INV');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -1) {
    echo ('BAN');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 0) {
    echo ('EVR');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 1 && $data['MAINT'] == "True") {
    echo ('MM');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 2 && $data['MAINT'] == "True") {
    //Continue and allow user to log in.
}
```

And what I see in the webbrowser is EVR. It seems like it doesn't even carry on from there?

Thanks.

Comment: _That should technically work but for some reason it doesn't._ Please tell us what _it works_ is and what it currently is doing.

Comment: What would you like to know? The value is $data['MAINT'] is False when I echo it in the browser. The code first connects to the myssql database and then it executes a myssql command which returns a few values. Before I do anything with the values I scan the LauncherInfo.txt file to find out what MAINT is equal to and in this case it is equal to False so then it checks the value that it got from the database (nAuthID) and currently I have it set to 1 in the database so it should technically continue with the code because MAINT equals false but it still stops when it gets to AuthId = 1.

Comment: Note: `if($var)` is the same as `if($var == true)`

Comment: The code should technically be correct. No one knows what's wrong?$data['MAINT'] is a string because it's from a txt file correct? So I tried adding quotes (") around it but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you checking for the existence of MAINT in $data, or are you checking to see it MAINT is true? If the latter, you should be doing comparison of strings, and not bools.

Comment: I'm checking to see if MAINT is true. So I would need to use quotes? Like so: $data['MAINT'] == "True"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking if `MAINT` is True  in the text file. You're essentially doing a comparison of strings. If you don't enclose it in quotes, PHP assumes it's a boolean (it's not). So you'll need to enclose it in double quotes like so:

```
if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 2 && $data['MAINT'] == "True") {
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -2) {
    die ('INV');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == -1) {
    die ('BAN');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 1 && $data['MAINT'] == "True") {
    die ('MM');
} else if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 0) {
    die ('EVR');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It should but it doesn't. This is confusing, I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: @FarbodD: What does `$AccountData` contain?

Comment: nEMID, nAuthID and sUserPass. If I change my AuthID in the myssql database to lets say -1 then it will output BAN.

Answer (score 1):

`file()` leaves the newlines in the strings, so `$data['Maint']` contains `"True\n"`, not `"True"`. You can use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` option to prevent this:

```
$file = file('LauncherInfo.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Another option is to trim the line before processing it -- this will remove trailing spaces as well.

```
foreach ($file as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if ($line) {
        $splitLine = explode(' = ',$line);
        $data[$splitLine[0]] = $splitLine[1];
    }
}
```

Then you also need to compare with `"True"`, not `True`, as in Amal Murali's answer:

```
if ($AccountData ['nAuthID'] == 2 && $data['MAINT'] == "True") {
```

The other problem you're having is that you're getting an error from the SQL query, and not checking for it. After calling `mssql_query()`, do:

```
if (!$exec) {
    die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

This will show the error message from MSSQL.

Comment: Currently my code looks like this: http://puu.sh/3pc7w.png and the output in the browser looks like this: http://puu.sh/3pc8I.png

Comment: It prints `EVR` if `$AccountData['nAuthID']` is 0. Your code checks that before checking `$data['MAINT']`, so none of these changes have any effect.

Comment: But $AccountData['nAuthID'] is 1 as we can see from here: http://puu.sh/3pcmD.png So because it is not 0 it should continue to the next else if statement?

Comment: What does `var_dump($AccountData)` show? Please edit it into your question as formatted text, not as a stupid link to an image.

Comment: Okay sorry, I thought that would be easier to understand. It says this: 'bool(false) EVR'

Comment: `$AccountData` should be an associative array, not a single value.

Comment: This is currently how the code looks like: http://puu.sh/3pczL.png I am not sure why it's displaying that. Unfortunately I can't put it here as formatted text. Hope you don't mind. Sorry.

Comment: I asked for the result of `var_dump($AccountData)`. Why can't you paste it into your question?

Comment: `var_dump($AccountData)` gives me this:  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\launcher\Login.php on line 23` And with semicolon it gaves me the result before. `bool(false)`

Comment: That means that `mssql_fetch_assoc()` is failing. You need to check for an error from `mssql_query()` before trying to fetch the result.

Comment: If you're not getting an error, it means that the query didn't match any rows in the database. Maybe there's a problem with `$user`.

Comment: Only error that I have always been getting which wasn't causing a problem before is this: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function sql_clean() in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\launcher\Login.php on line 7` And nothing else. This is on line 7 and 8: `$user = sql_clean($_GET['Username']);
$passhash = sql_clean($_GET['Password']);`

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Since `sql_clean()` doesn't exist, you're setting `$user` and `$passhash` to empty values. `sql_clean()` is not a standard PHP function, it sounds like you're missing a `require` that loads it from somewhere.

Comment: I've been using that for how long now and it hasn't caused me any problems before. This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/YdC1ANC2 I don't load anything from anywhere. Also $user needs to be an empty value until it's assigned something.

Comment: `sql_clean()` is defined later in your file. I don't know why it's saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: Me neither. So does no one know how to fix this? Damn.

Comment: Try checking for invisible characters like BOM.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Check if your IDE has a function to do it (PhpStorm has `File->Remove BOM`).

Comment: I'm running this on my own computer, using a program called wampserver. It's 3:36am so I think I better go sleep. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try cutting and pasting the file, sometimes that clears problems like this.